# Composite Setting Values not Saved after Closing the App

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

By the end of the Saving function, composite settings are saved and retrieved correctly. However after closing down the Visual Studio run time instance and running the project again, composite values are back to default. What could be wrong here?

**Save**

```
private void SaveSettings()
    {
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        var compositeTest = (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["Test"];

        // Save test
        compositeTest["A"] = PropA;
        compositeTest["B"] = PropB;
        compositeTest["C"] = PropC;

        // Retrieve test
        var a = compositeTest["A"];
        var b = compositeTest["B"];
        var c = compositeTest["C"];
}
```

**Build**

```
private void BuildSettings()
    {
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        var compositeTest = (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["Test"];

            if (compositeTest == null)
            {
                Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue();

                composite["A"] = PropA= 1;
                composite["B"] = PropB= 1;
                composite["C"] = PropC= 1;

                localSettings.Values["Test"] = composite;
            }
            else
            {
                PropA= (int)compositeTest["A"];
                PropB= (int)compositeTest["B"];
                PropC= (int)compositeTest["C"];
            }
 }
```

Comment: what the type of `PropA`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the composite setting to the Values `IPropertySet` of the `LocalSettings`:

```
private void SaveSettings()
{
    var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    var compositeTest = new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue();

    compositeTest["A"] = "A";

    localSettings.Values["Test"] = compositeTest;

}

private void BuildSettings()
{
    var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    var compositeTest = localSettings.Values["Test"] as Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue;

    var a = compositeTest["A"];
}
```

**Edit:** Try to reset the `localSettings.Values["Test"]` key in your `SaveSettings()` method:

```
private void SaveSettings()
{
    var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    var compositeTest = (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["Test"];

    // Save test
    compositeTest["A"] = PropA;
    compositeTest["B"] = PropB;
    compositeTest["C"] = PropC;

    // Retrieve test
    var a = compositeTest["A"];
    var b = compositeTest["B"];
    var c = compositeTest["C"];

    localSettings.Values["Test"] = compositeTest;
}
```

Comment: I do not think there is a need for "new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue()" in the Save function since this is done in the BuildSettings each time the ViewModel is started.

Comment: Try to reset the localSettings.Values["Test"] key in your SaveSettings() method. I edited my answer.